# Создание вложенных данных в сериализаторе Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

возникла проблема при создании вложенных данных в сериализаторе **Django Rest Framework**. Я хочу, чтобы при передачи в `request.data` полей «slug» и «schedules» создавалась запись в БД с этими данными **+ «author» равен `request.user`.**

**Моя попытка:**

*models.py*

```
class ShareLink(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=False)
    schedules = models.TextField(blank=False)
    author = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='sharelinks_used', blank=True)
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        str = 'ShareLink: id: {}, slug: {}'.format(self.id, self.slug)
        return str
```

*serializers.py*

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('schedules', 'photos', 'is_deleted', 'is_banned')
...

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    profile = ProfileSerializer(
        many=False,
        read_only=True
    )

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'password', 'email', 'profile')
...

class ShareLinkSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = ShareLink
        fields = ('id', 'slug', 'schedules', 'author', 'users', 'views', 'is_deleted')
```

*views.py*

```
class ShareLinkCreate(APIView):

    def post(self, request):

        serializer = ShareLinkSerializer(data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data(), status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

**Ошибка:**

— Отправляю POST-запрос с form-data, где slug = "some slug", schedules = "some schedules".

Ответ:

```
{
    "author": [
        "This field is required."
    ]
}
```

Прошу помочь с данным вопросом. Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Делаем поле только для чтения и при создании нового экземпляра - прокидываем автора из контекста запроса.

```
class ShareLinkSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    author = serializers.ReadOnlyField()

    class Meta:
        model = ShareLink
        fields = ('id', 'slug', 'schedules', 'author', 'users', 'views', 'is_deleted')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        validated_data['author'] = self.context['request'].user
        return super(ShareLinkSerializer, self).create(validated_data)
```

Чтобы не заморачиваться с вьюхой(прокидывать контекст в сериализатор вручную) - можно использовать **CreateAPIView**:

```
from rest_framework import permissions, generics

class ShareLinkCreate(generics.CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = ShareLinkSerializer

    # Разрешаем доступ только авторизованным, 
    # т.к. при создании анонимным пользователем - в сериализаторе будет ошибка
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
```

Comment: Спасибо, что ответили на мой вопрос. Но у меня возникли некоторые трудности. 1. При первом запросе отправил slug, schedules. В базе данных появилась корректная запись. Но вышла следующая ошибка следующая ошибка: `TypeError at /api/v1/ShareLink.create/ Object of type User is not JSON serializable` 2. После первого пункта, я отправил запрос с немного другими данными от этого же пользователя и вышла следующая ошибка: `IntegrityError at /api/v1/ShareLink.create/ UNIQUE constraint failed: account_sharelink.author_id `

Comment: Попробуй сделать в классе ShareLinkSerializer поле user которое будет обрабатывать author например `author=UserSerializer(many=False)`

Comment: @Necko, спасибо. Первая ошибка исправлена, теперь выдает все поля ShareLink, но вторая проблема с `UNIQUE constraint failed: account_sharelink.author_id` все еще актуальна

Comment: UPD: Извиняюсь, вторая ошибка вызвана тем, что я неправильно указал тип поля «author» в модели. Всем огромнейшее спасибо за помощь!